# If universe is expanding why is the distance between planets not increasing?

Tags: planet, space, general-relativity

General relativity tells us space is expanding.Then why does the distance between planets and heavenly bodies increase?

Comment: Galaxy-Galaxy(dark energy>gravity) but planet-planet/star(dark energy<gravity)

Comment: Likely, changeover is at cluster or even supercluster level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distances between planets and stars do not expand as long as they are bound together by gravity sufficiently. This is true even at the scale of an entire Galaxy.